# Django ModelForm - Performance issue

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using ModelForm to allow multiple rows edit at the same time. It is a very simple form that has series of yes_no columns. The model looks like:

## models.py

```
class Yn(models.Model):
    yn_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([
            self.description,
        ])

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yn'

class Invoice(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    invoice_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
    invoice_sent_yn = models.ForeignKey('Yn', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='invoice_sent_yn', related_name="invoice_sent_yn")
    confirm_receipt_yn = models.ForeignKey('Yn', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='confirm_receipt_yn', related_name="confirm_receipt_yn")
    paid_yn = models.ForeignKey('Yn', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='paid_yn', related_name="paid_yn")
```

## forms.py

```
class InvoiceGridEdit(ModelForm):
    model = Invoice
    fields = ['description','invoice_date','invoice_sent_yn', 'confirm_receipt_yn', 'paid_yn']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JurisGridEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        ...

InvoiceFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.Invoice, form=InvoiceGridEdit)
```

## views.py

```
class InvoiceUpdateGrid(CreateView):
    template_name = "/invoice_update_grid.html"
    model = Invoice
    form_class = InvoviceViewEditForm

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("account_login")

    def get(self, request, *args, *kwargs):
        self.object = None
        customer_number = self.request.GET.get('customer_number')
        invoice_form = InvoiceFormSet(queryset=Invoice.objects.filter(customer_number = customer_number)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(invoice_form=invoice_form))
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        invoice_form = InvoiceFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (invoice_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(invoice_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(invoice_form)

    def form_valid(self, invoice_form):
        ...
        ...
        invoice_form.save()
        return redirect("customer_list")

    def form_invalid(self, invoice_form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(invoice_form=invoice_form))
```

The forms works fine, get and post works, except, it takes a while (~30 sec) to retrieve and update. Using django-debug-toolbar, it looks like the yn columns retrieve separately for each column for each row (~2k rows). The Yn table only has 3 rows -1 - Unknown, 0 - No, 1 - Yes.

I tried to search for work around to stop the craziness of Django hitting the DB 900 times per retrieval. I found something about caching but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put code that is making data retrieval.

Comment: Edited with the views. Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) or preferably [NullBooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#nullbooleanfield)

Comment: Using prefetch helps with the retrieval speed. Thanks.